# Pdf.js with react and django

Tags: reactjs, django, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I'am trying to develope a pdf viewer with Django framework using React.js as Frontend

The problem is that the pdfviewer works perfectly on react project, but when I build it (npm run build) and copy it to the django project it doesn't work.

I think that the problems is with paths, care to suggest a method and steps to do that correctly

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: No, there is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was in the paths.

Here are the steps that I have followed to make it work.

1- copy the folder "pdfjs.2.0" into "static/js"

2- copy all the files of the folder "pdfjs.2.0/build" into "pdfjs2.0/web"

3- open the file "pdfjs2.0/web/viewer.html" and modify the line 36
Here is the line after modification

4-open the file "pdfjs2.0/web/viewer.js" and modify the line 229

Here is the line after the modification

Value : "./pdf.worker.js"

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

> > X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW'